# What does it mean for a coefficient to have singularities?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a paper that mentions ordinary differential equations with singular coefficients. I'm not sure what the author means by "singular coefficients". The paper is about uniqueness results for such ODE's.

Comment: This means that the coefficients are zero for some values of the independent variable.

Answer (score 1):

As Artem said, singular coefficients are those that turn to $0$. More precisely, a singularity occurs when the coefficient of *the highest derivative* in the equation turns to zero. For example, 
$$
xy''+y'+y+1=0
$$
has a singularity at $0$, but 
$$
y''+xy'+y+1=0
$$
does not.

At a singular point, the proof of the standard uniqueness/existence theorems breaks down since the equation cannot be solved for the highest derivative. And the existence and uniqueness may indeed fail: the initial value problem 
$$
xy'-y =0, \quad y(0)=a
$$
has no solutions when $a\ne 0$ and infinitely many solutions (namely $y=kx$ for any $k$) when $a=0$.